# Angularjs not working in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat, mean-stack

below is my angular js html file 
and i am accessing using http://localhost:3000/modulename/create
the problem is angularjs is not working like for instance the ng repeat is empty 
in template-ing whereas when we  console the object in javascript it  return values please refer highlighted section in  below screenshot for reference purposes

[image]

angular app.js

```
    angular.module('scotchTodo', ['todoController']);


 angular.module('todoController', [])

    // inject the Todo service factory into our controller


    .controller('ContactController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http, Todos) {


        $scope.contacts = [
        {id:0, 'name': 'PremAseem', 'email':'hello@gmail.com', 'phone': '123-2343-44'}
    ];
    console.log($scope.contacts)


    }]);
```

angular  html code

```
<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="scotchTodo">
<head>
  <!-- META -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

  <title>Node/Angular Todo App</title>

  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- load bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    html          { overflow-y:scroll; }
    body          { padding-top:50px; }
    #todo-list        { margin-bottom:30px; }
    #todo-form        { margin-bottom:50px; }
  </style>

  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->


  <script src="../../admin/js/app.js"></script>  <!--load up our controller -->

</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER -->
<body >
<div  ng-controller="ContactController">
    <form class="well">
    <label>Name</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newcontact.name"/>
    <label>Email</label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newcontact.email"/>
    <label>Phone</label> 
        <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="newcontact.phone"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="newcontact.id" />
     <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveContact()" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead> 
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.phone }}</td>
    <td>
        <a  href="#" ng-click="edit(contact.id)">edit</a> | 
        <a href="#" ng-click="delete(contact.id)">delete</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>    
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you take out the `mainController` in the body tag?

Comment: still the issue persists

Comment: your code show you've never declared ContactController on the app module. It looks like its just a normal function.

Comment: how should i declare ContactController on app module

Comment: the same way you declared the main controller.

Comment: Check browser console for errors thrown. Should be helpful clues there

Comment: @charlietfl in my attached screenshot we can view console and it has no error whatsoever .

Comment: exact same code works fine in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJ6kpJimRH1o3D94NRSC?p=preview). What if you just write `{{contacts}}` in the html file somewhere? Does it render the object?

Comment: the code base is not working as expected in nodejs+expressjs @BennettAdams , that is base problem !

Comment: Well, you don't actually show any node/express code, so the point is that the angular code isn't the problem.

Comment: @BennettAdams in process soon  , but  why should client side codebase have dependability from server side code  raises a kinda weird question !

Comment: @BennettAdams please find nodejs code in rar file from below url
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sJE1z-87iTd2ZqTFAyWnJybDg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with consolidate templating. Thanks @nirmal for issue deduction.  The solution was to change angularjs templating.

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('scotch', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue because of your view engine used in nodejs/express
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate
    Basically most of the server side/client side view engines used the {{ data }} pattern for templating, in your code your bindings are truncated by your view engine.
    Html Response of your /api call giving the HTML snippets with out your actual binding you made in your code.

```
(1)
    If you move you modulename.html, app.js inside public folder and if you access the same through node server. It works as expected.
    You can try this.
    Compare the response HTML snippets for below two cases from Browser Network Tab,
        1. /api
        2. /modulename.html  // after placing modulename.html in public folder
(2)
    For any problem in Javascript frameworks, browser console is our best friend. You can navigate to console and access scope object of element you can get the "contacts" object.
    Or you can bind you contacts object model to any text box using ng-model, or ng-bind directives.
    you can get your contacts value in html.

(3)
    If you want to still use view engine in server side, even though you have master piece angular in browser. You can choose ng-bind directive for you angularjs template.
    It's always better approach to use ng-bind directive in our templates, instead of {{}} pattern.

Hope this helps you on the issue. Please feel free to ping me, if not resolved.
```

[image]

Comment: can we implement something on lines
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614183/angularjs-interpolate-provider-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.module('scotchTodo', ['todoController']);


angular.module('todoController', [])

  // inject the Todo service factory into our controller


  .controller('ContactController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http, Todos) {
      scope.contacts = [];
      var data = {id:0, 'name': 'PremAseem', 'email':'hello@gmail.com', 'phone': '123-2343-44'};
      $scope.contacts.push(data);
  console.log($scope.contacts)


  }]);
```

Comment: issue persist and there is correction is above post scope.contacts = []; should be $scope.contacts = []; right